# Listening for a table change instead of looping over a select?

Tags: mysql, perl, triggers

I've a perl application looping over a mysql select to find commands to run..

I'm wondering how to avoid this loop/select.

Can I use a trigger ? Can I listen for something from mysql ?

Anyway, I think that's a common problem, but I'm not finding the correct ressource..

Comment: You weren't exactly clear about the problem and looping. Basically, do you want to have your script notified when data in MySQL table changes?

Comment: yes, exactly. or something similar

Comment: In that case, look for MySQL UDF sys_exec which allows you to invoke an external program from within stored procedure or a trigger.